# Ext JS EditorGridPanel - How to split cell to show multiple rows

Tags: extjs, extjs3

In Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel table how to split a cell to have two or three rows?

Like the below image

[image]

Comment: Which Ext JS version?

Comment: In Ext 4+ it is easy - you can, instead of splitting, only set rowspan first column cells. In Ext 3.4 on the other hand it is not that easy. Each row is rendered as separate table wrapped with div, so rowspan will not work. Probably the easiest way is to change style of cells in first column and render them over those below. I'll come up with something later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do a kind of rowspan instead of row splitting. IMO it's easier and it looks the same as grid on attached image. Example code:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    [...],

    // hook up events
    initComponent: function () {
        Ext.grid.GridPanel.prototype.initComponent.call(this);

        this.getView().on('refresh', this.updateRowSpan, this);
        this.getView().on('rowupdated', this.updateRowSpan, this);
    },

    onLayout : function(vw, vh) {
        this.updateRowSpan();
    },

    // set span on rows
    updateRowSpan: function() {
        var columns = this.getColumnModel().config,
            view = this.getView(),
            store = this.getStore(),
            rowCount = store.getCount(),

            column = columns[0], // put propert column index here
            dataIndex = column.dataIndex,

            spanCell = null,
            spanCount = null;
            spanValue = null;

        for (var row = 0; row < rowCount; ++row) {
            var cell = view.getCell(row, 0),
                record = store.getAt(row),
                value = record.get(dataIndex);

            if (spanValue != value) {
                if (spanCell !== null) {
                    this.setSpan(Ext.get(spanCell), spanCount);
                }

                spanCell = cell;
                spanCount = 1;
                spanValue = value;
            } else {
                spanCount++;
            }
        }

        if (spanCell !== null) {
            this.setSpan(Ext.get(spanCell), spanCount);
        }
    },

    // set actual span on row
    setSpan: function(cell, count) {
        var view = this.getView(),
            innerCell = Ext.get(cell.down('*')),
            height = cell.getHeight(),
            width = cell.getWidth();

        cell.setStyle('position', 'relative');
        if (count == 1) {
            innerCell.setStyle('position', '');
            innerCell.setStyle('height', '');
            innerCell.setStyle('height', '');
        } else {
            innerCell.setStyle('position', 'absolute');
            innerCell.setStyle('height', (height * count - cell.getPadding('tb') - innerCell.getPadding('tb')) + 'px');
            innerCell.setStyle('width', (width - cell.getPadding('lr') - innerCell.getPadding('lr')) + 'px');
        }
    }
});
```

This code changes style of `.x-grid3-cell-inner` by applying `position: absolute` and big enough size to cover rows below. Notice that you must also apply some opaque background to make it work. Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/RpxZ5/8/

I first wrote code for Ext JS 4, if you interested, here is working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/wQSQM/3/

Comment: It does work but there is one problem. Since `.x-grid3-cell-inner` is applied `position:absolute`  the `forcefit` functionality stops working for that row. You can check in the jsfiddle you provided. Any idea how that can be fixed?
This problem is found in version 3.4 only. It works fine with 4.x